# 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using PHPMailer library and Amazon SES service. I have created SES account and verified my domain by adding TXT record and also CNAME records for DKIM settings.

In SES `Email Addresses` I have verified one email address - `kakumanivrn@gmail.com`. Using PHPMailer I have used SES credentials and sent email from `kakumanivrn@gmail.com` to `kakumanivr@gmail.com`. I did debugging and got this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself. In limited SES account, I can send only email to verified recipients using verified senders. So I have to verify both emails and it's working now.

Comment: @Varun_Kakumani please mark your own answer as accepted, thanks.

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni, I cannot accept my own answer at least after 2 days. Thanks for the suggestion. Please upvote it, so that it is helpful for others.